# Traffic Control (TC) unstable results in Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I'm trying to use Traffic Control (TC) inside a Docker container.
I'm Using TC through tcset command (part of python tcconfig package) to set the new flow rule on eth0 which is the container's interface to the network. The container is run using the option "--cap-add=NET_ADMIN" to add networking administration right needed by TC. The real bandwidth is then tested using iperf3 client that can connect to an iperf3 server on another docker container, in the same network.
The full command I'm using to run the container and get access to an interactive shell is:

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it <IMG-ID> /bin/bash
```

Where  is my image's id. The image is based on ubuntu image and has TC, python3 and tcconfig installed into.

The bitrate measured by iperf3 without TC rules between the two containers is about 80GBps.

Now I want to control the eth0's bandwidth to provide for example 100 Mbps. The command to set the bandwidth is:

```
tcset eth0 --rate 100mbps --overwrite
```

Where the --overwrite option is needed to overwrite previous rules on eth0 interface.

This configuration seems to work but has some strange measures like the first one that exceed the link limit I set, as shown in the following picture: [image: iperf test 100Mbps]

The problem become bigger when I apply low bandwidths to the eth0 interface. If I apply 1Mbps I got strange results as shown in the following picture:[image: iperf test 1Mbps]
The overall bandwidth during the 20s period is 1,44 at sender side and 1.00 at receiver side.

I think tc applies the flow rule with a not stable algorithm that fluctuate exploding to 0 and than back to 4,68 Mbps, then 0 again and so on.
I also think that with high bandwidths (more than 50Mbps) fluctuations are less relevant and it is harder to observe them but they are still present. I need to further investigate on that.

However, is there any solution to make TC more stable at low bandwidths?